# [FromBody]. Param value in Post Controller is always NULL

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am new to .net web apps. My usecase is make a post call with XML as body. I am trying to make a call through postman, but the param value received in my controller is always null. Below are the thing I have:

He is my XML body:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <document>
    <id>123456</id>
    <content>This is document that I posted...</content>
    <author>Michał Białecki</author>
    <links>
      <link>2345</link>
      <link>5678</link>
    </links>
  </document>
```

Here is the DTO object I am using:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "document", Namespace = "")]
public class ABC
{
    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(DataType = "string", ElementName = "author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "links")]
    public LinkDto Links { get; set; }
}

public class LinkDto
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "link")]
    public string[] Link { get; set; }
}
```

Apart from this, I have also added this in my Startup.cs
`services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();`

And at last this is my controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UploadFileController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public void RegisterDocument([FromBody] Document dto)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inside the controller");
    }
}
```

This is how I am calling it from postman:
[image]

One other thing I noticed while in debugging mode is I am seeing these errors as well:
[image]

Can someone please help? I have tried various solutions but not able to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `AddXmlSerializerFormatters()`:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
    .AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Your xml should like below(remove `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`):

```
<document>
    <id>123456</id>
    <content>This is document that I posted...</content>
    <author>Michał Białecki</author>
    <links>
      <link>2345</link>
      <link>5678</link>
    </links>
</document>
```

Your Action need to change `Document` to `ABC` :

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] ABC dto)
{
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer. It is working. Adding ".AddXmlSerializerFormatters()" I dont know how I missed that. Looked so trivial.